# Rollback a changeset in tfs

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2012

Using visual studio 2012 and TFS 2012, I would like to rollback a changeset to the prior one.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

In TFS 2012,

1. View the history of the thing you want to rollback.
2. Select the changeset you want to roll back.
3. Right click on the changset and choose "Rollback".
4. Check that the pending changes are correct (the rollback command will revert the entire changeset not just the file you selected)
5. Check in.

In TFS 2010, you can call the `tf rollback` command from a visual studio command prompt, or you can install the [TFS power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) and use the same process as above

Comment: Please help me clarify something, when I select in the explorer an old changeset and then click 'rollback', does it rollback to that changeset or to one before??

Comment: It rolls back the changeset you have selected to the previous one.

Comment: Means any changes after that change set would also be removed?
If we are talking about full project and changes are in different files in different change sets?

Comment: In VS 2015, when I select single changeset, I can rollback changes on all files, that were affected by this changeset (by single click). When I select multiple changesets, I can rollback changes just on the file I've selected. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How to rollback only specific files in a changeset and not entire changeset? Is there a way or shd i get specific dates version of the files i want(Is the only way) ?

Answer (score 27):

In TFS / Visual Studio 2012, you have a few options.

**Rollback to a specific version**

In Source Control Explorer:

- Right Click the branch you wish to roll back
- Click Rollback...
- Choose Rollback to a specific version
- Enter the changeset number you wish to roll back to.

**Rollback a single changeset (you can do this through the dialog loaded above too)**

- Right click the changeset you wish to rollback
- Choose Rollback entire changset

Checkin the rollback.

Answer (score -9):

I have never worked with TFS 2012 but this works in 2010

Get specific version and pick the version you want to roll-back to
and then check in that code again.

Comment: This is not a rollback. This is a check-in.

Comment: It is not just check in @QualityCatalyst. When you roll back  change set X, if you want to save the undoing, after rolling back, you should check in to have the solution without changes in change set X.

Comment: @Fery, you are right. The answer here though does not talk about a rollback. It talks about a pure check-in based on historic code.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst yeah , you are right. Today I just release for rolling back you can not get a version and then check in, you must roll back a/ to change set then check in.