# Rollback entire solution/project to specific changeset in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, rollback, changeset, checkin

I am at changeset 121.

I want to rollback down to version 112, ignoring all the changes I've made since then.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15301567/75500) answer but I can't find the command in the menu.
I'm struggling with this over an hour now and can't find the real solution. All I'm trying to do is rollback to changeset 112 disregarding all the changes made since then. Just like going back in time entirely erasing the past.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Just like going back in time entirely erasing the past.

tfs does not allow you to do this. This rollback operation will be a new changeset 122 which will rollback everything to 112.

[Roll Back Changesets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194956%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Actually I don't remind leaving evidence and make it up into a new changeset, but I want that changeset to be a simple mirror of the changeset I'm rolling back to.

Comment: Ok, then the link above should help to do this. Did you try?

Comment: Yes. Looks like it's working. I tried [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194956%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#to_one), so after making the rollback I guess I should checking and I'm over with it, right?

Comment: Yes, this will create new changeset, which will be marked as Rollback.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps you can also help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154704/nivo-slider-disappears-while-slide-is-being-changed-in-ie-8) question too? The sample website is [here](http://level.azurewebsites.net).

Comment: So what you're saying is that if your most recent changeset is `122` and you rollback to `112` then `123` will be created which mirrors `112`. If you want to then go back to your `122` you'd rollback to `122` which would create changeset `124` which mirrors `122`?

Answer (score 15):

You can actually do that. In Source Control, view the history of your solution project, then select all the changesets down till the one you want to rollback to and then right click-> rollback. That will roll back all changesets in order, effectively undoing ALL changes made to the solution folder

Comment: It doesnt work that way.  That wil only show changesets that change the sln (ie the addition or removal of projects).